# SwiftUI - setting a SwiftUIView as start screen on a Game Project

Tags: scenekit, swiftui, xcode11

I am trying to set a SwiftUIView as the start screen on a Game Project.

I tried setting SceneDelegate.swift as:

```
// Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: SwiftUIView())
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

But when I build app, still see the standard ship.scn

Does anyone know how to change the start view for a game project, from the ship.scn to a SwiftUI View?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It "looks" like either let windowScene is failing or Main interface is still calling your storyboard. Did you start your project with a storyboard, then attempt to remove it?

I use this code in AppDelegate...  hope it helps!

```
let win = UIWindow()        
win.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds        
win.backgroundColor = UIColor.black        
win.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MainVC())
win.makeKeyAndVisible()
window = win
return true
```